# Ajax Responses multiple times

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am working in an ASP.NET Core project. Based on ajax call we are displaying data. But I am strange that the ajax function is being called once but appropriate controller action method gets call multiple time. I put debugger to verify that function is get called once but result come in success section multiple times.

**Here is my jQuery code:**

```
function reloadAllOpenSchedule(currentMonth, currentYear) {
    var events = {
        url: appSetting + 'Calendar/GetSchdules?currentMonth=' + currentMonth + "&currentYear=" + currentYear,
        type: 'GET',
        data: {},
        success: function () {
             // Response comes multiple times
        }
    }
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', events);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);
}
```

**Here is my controller method:**

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetSchdules(int currentMonth, int currentYear)
{
     // my codes here
     var rows = eventList.ToArray();
     return Json(rows);
}
```

I am making call of reloadAllOpenSchedule(currentMonth, currentYear) function from below code

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
...some code
viewRender: function (view, element) {
...some code
 currentMonth = view.start.getMonth() + 1;
 currentYear = view.start.getFullYear();
reloadAllOpenSchedule(currentMonth ,currentYear );
...
});
```

If ajax call is made for current month then Action Method is called 2 time, for next month it call 3 times and so on.

Comment: Please update your post to include where you are calling your `reloadAllOpenSchedule` function from.

Comment: I like to wrap my ajax call function in an if statement that is dependent on a boolean flag I set to true prior to the call, and then I set it to false within the call. This has been highly effective at preventing uncalled for ajax calls. Without seeing where you are making your ajax call, maybe this technique will prevent hours of tracking down why it's making an unsolicited ajax call.

Comment: @I.R.R. and Adam Chubbuck, I have edited code as you asked. Please suggest

Comment: This is not the recommended way to load events in fullCalendar. Instead use the `events` property. For your requirement I would recommend the approach documented here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function and you should find it works much better. fullCalendar will automatically run the function again every time you go to a view or date range for which is has not already downloaded events. I would also recommend amending your server code to accept specific start and end dates instead of a month. That way, the calendar will get exactly what it needs, even if the user views only one day